# Where is mount location / unix device name on Mac OS for HackRF USB hardware?

Tags: macos, usb, mount

I'm looking for the OS USB device mount point established when a HackRF is connected to a Macbook using USB-C. Specifically I need the  the path to the device. On Ubuntu this would be `/dev/bus/usb`.

The device is recognized by the OS. It shows up under System Information --> Hardware --> USB. diskutil list does not list the device. `dmesg` does not have anything useful. And `lsusb` does not work on this OS.

What is the equivalent on Mac OS Ventura 13.3?

Comment: Unless this is a storage device, `diskutil` won’t be applicable.  Nothing will be created in the `/dev/` folder if there isn’t a driver for it.  Does this device indicate macOS compatibility?

Comment: @IconDaemon I have already installed `hackrf` using macports. Did you paste the wrong link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent. `/dev/bus/usb` is a Linux-specific creation that does not exist on other systems.

You can install `hackrf` from HomeBrew to interact with your device. The tool uses `libusb` to automatically find your device on the available USB-busses based on the vendor and product IDs that they advertise when plugged in.

Your question seems to be an XY-problem - meaning that you are actually trying to solve some practical problem, which you are not telling us about, and in the process think that you need to solve this other problem. You would get better answers if you asked the main problem instead.

Comment: I want to mount the hackrf to a docker container so the container can interact with the device. Is this possible?

Comment: No, not at the moment. The terminology of "mounting" in this context is Linux-specific - it is not the way that works on other operating systems. Docker for Mac has not yet implemented a USB pass-through feature, so as of right now, you would have to implement that yourself. You could try running the container in privileged mode, but that would probably defeat the entire point of running it in a container anyways.

Comment: Here's a link you can follow on the progress of getting USB pass-through for macOS supported in Docker: https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/149  (basically it's 5 years of "will come later").

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks for the help and info.